# Need an algorithm to optimize grouping python dictionaries in hierarchical form

Tags: python, algorithm

Previously I asked a question on how to group dictionaries in a list in hierarchical structure. [Grouping Python dictionaries in hierachical form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791778/grouping-python-dictionaries-in-hierachical-form)

This method works fine, but I now need to optimize. The dictionaries has a big memory overhead and this grouping gets pretty slow when we are dealing with huge number of records.

I was wondering if there is any algorithm I could use to reduce the time needed to do the grouping.

P.S: I wouldn't mind changing the data-structure as long as it gives me the same hierarchical format.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using Python 2.x, replace `items` with `iteritems` to get rid of some of the memory overhead.

Comment: I'm sure that the good folks here at SO would be happy to take a look at this, but you should also post this at [codereview.stackexchange](codereview.stackexchange.com). That's where this question really belongs

Comment: @larsmans: Can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Didn't know about codereview, should I close my question here ?

Comment: `items` returns a list of items. `iteritems` returns an iterator over the items, i.e. a lightweight object that is little more than a pointer into the `dict`.

Comment: don't close your question here. I've already flagged it for migration. It'll get migrated automatically now, and you'll know when it happens :)